# Java Serialization not working, appears broken because of IDE

Tags: java, git, serialization

**EDIT:** The error was caused by Netbeans not the code. Post has been edited to show all the code since the Git files are being removed.

---

I have a group project at school to design a tower defense game and I have been attempting to add Serialization.

Here is the code:

```
public class Serialization implements Serializable {

private static FileOutputStream file;
private static ObjectOutputStream write;

public static boolean checkFile(String name){
    boolean check = false;
    check = new File("log",name+".ser").isFile();
    return check;
}

public static void createFile(String name) {
    try {
        file = new FileOutputStream("log/"+name+".ser");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static ObjectOutputStream openFile(String name) {
    try {
        file = new FileOutputStream("log/"+name+".ser");
        write = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return write;
}

public static void addLine(ObjectOutputStream con,Object data) {
    try {
        con.writeObject(data);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void readLine(String name){
    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = new FileInputStream("log/"+name+".ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        System.out.println(in.readObject());
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public static void closeFile(ObjectOutputStream con){
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Serialization.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

I eventually abandoned it for two reasons. One it was overkill (trying to have a central class that handles multiple serialization files) and two I could not get it to work with what I am about to talk about.

What I really wanted was to serialize the enemyArray. This holds every living enemy in the game and all their information (stats). If you scroll down to line 192 that is what is left of my serialization attempts:

```
public void serialize(){
    if (Serialization.checkFile("test")==false){
        Serialization.createFile("test");
    }
    ObjectOutputStream connection = Serialization.openFile("test");
    for (int x=0;x<enemyArray.length;x++){
            if (enemyArray[x]!=null){
                Serialization.addLine(connection,enemyArray[x]);
            }
        }
    //Serialization.addLine(connection,enemyArray);
    Serialization.closeFile(connection);
    enemyArray = null;
    Serialization.readLine("test");
    //System.out.println(enemyArray[0].id);
//      try {
//          FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("log/test.ser");
//          ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
//          out.writeObject(enemyArray);
//          out.writeUTF(t);
//          // Do work here
//          for (int x=0;x<enemyArray.length;x++){
//              if (enemyArray[x]!=null){
//                  Enemy tmp = enemyArray[x];
//                  System.out.println(tmp+" >>> "+enemyArray[x]);
//                  out.writeObject(tmp);
//              }
//          }
//          out.close();
//          fileOut.close();
//      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
//          Logger.getLogger(EnemyController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//      } catch (IOException ex) {
//          Logger.getLogger(EnemyController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//      }
}
}
```

It will create the file but will not save anything to it. **What is wrong with the code?** from what I studied enemyArray shouldn't be static so I removed that and still no change.

Comment: Can you comment on down votes. I'm in lab tell 9pm tonight but can add code and my examples later if you need.

Comment: Look at my selected answer. This turned out to be an IDE bug that cost me hours or re-coding and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error after some troubleshooting in the computer lab with my group. Hopefully this can help anyone who finds themselves in my situation or in a similar Java file read/ write issue.

My IDE, [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), shows the file in the files and project list once it is dynamically created, but because it was filled with serialized data and was created after the project was opened and run it would only display an empty file when in reality there is actually data inside the file. String data is fine so it may only be certain data types (like serialized objects) that trigger this error.

Several different versions of my code were correct but they all seemed broken because an empty file was returned to the IDE. The solution is two fold:

1. Manually check it through your file explorer. It will show a size and can be opened in another editor but may still be buggy in the IDE you ran the program in.
2. Close down your IDE and on reopening, at least in Netbeans case, the file should be updated correctly.

On a similar note Netbeans may just all together keep showing the empty file instead of offering you the option to select the files encoding. Just view the file in your explorer in this case and if the size is greater than 0 you know your code is ok. This is purely an IDE error.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a  out.flush(); brefore you close thre output stream.